Error updating DB to 5.78.1 - and it almost finished!
Updating CiviCRM to 5.78.1 and was at the database update. It appeared it was about to finish when I got a Core Exception telling me that it couldn't create table civicrm_search_display since it already exists.  Which is does - I verified via Show Tables.
Full error is here:
CRM_Core_Exception: Cannot execute CREATE TABLE `civicrm_search_display` ( `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Unique SearchDisplay ID', `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Unique name for identifying search display', `label` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Label for identifying search display to administrators', `saved_search_id` int unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK to saved search table.', `type` varchar(128) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Type of display', `settings` text DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Configuration data for the search display', `acl_bypass` boolean DEFAULT FALSE COMMENT 'Skip permission checks and ACLs when running this display.', PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE INDEX `UI_saved_search__id_name`(`saved_search_id`, `name`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC: DB Error: already exists in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/mixin/lib/civimix-schema/src/SchemaHelper.php on line 66

Any ideas on this?  It was sooooo close!
Thanks!

Possible workaround: backup the table, remove it from the db, re-run upgrade, restore the table data from the backup.

What version are you upgrading from?

Updating from old (2022) 5.48.?
Wordpress is up to date at 6.6.2
I did attempt again with an LTS version 5.75.2 and, while I didn't get that same error, it just never finished - update process was hung even after three hours.  Which basically just caused all extensions to fail.
So I am waiting now until our donation folk can give me free reign again for a day and I will try disabling all extensions and removing the non-core ones and trying it again.
